# How can I see my full character without idling?

Tags: fallout-4

Is there a way I can see my full character without having to tilt the camera down at him? The only way that works is having my character idle and rotating the camera around him.

Comment: The linked duplicate is about looking at the face, not the whole character body. You can tell this if you read the accepted answer. My answer to that question, which says how to view the whole body, has the *least* upvotes.

Comment: @DCShannon this is true, but I also believe the _highest_ voted but not the accepted answer says the same thing (for the most part)?

Comment: @TimmyJim It's pretty close to my answer, yes. Doesn't actually say how to zoom out to see the whole body. I should have also pointed out that the asker edited their question to make it clearer that they meant the face. Also, the accepted answer indicates the asker's intent, as they are the one who chooses it. So, question body + accepted answer = they want the face.